# WP site generating weird session id next to page url

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Few pages of my WordPress site generating weird session id next to page url for example http://www.example.com/?wvsessionid=wvac7224adb9a344b4b05354762584a621 . I don’t know where this coming from. bad thing is google indexing them & it creating duplicate content issue. where should i look for this issue & any idea , how I can solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Joomla site generating weird session ID's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803840/why-is-my-joomla-site-generating-weird-session-ids)

Comment: @Areeb this is Wordpress not Joomla. Are these issues applicable to both?

Comment: @Martin The environment is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of two things:

- some plugin is generating this, in that case search in plugins code to look for `wvsessionid` phrase which will tell you which plugin is generating this and why.

  - another option is some injected code due to hacking but that less likely as this parameter wouldn't be of much help.